# How to set WordPress to sub directory with Python(Django) project in nginx?

Tags: django, wordpress, nginx

I want to set `WordPress` to the sub directory of the server that uses the root directory in the `Python`(`Django`) project.

- `sample.com/` -> for `Python(Django) project`
- `sample.com/wordpress` -> for `wordpress project`

The `nginx` configuration file is set as bellow, but if I access the URL `sample.com/wordpress` that I want to show `WordPress`, it will show `404 Not Found`.

How should I make the `nginx` configuration file in this case?

---

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name sample.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem;


    location =/fabicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}

    location /static{
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
    }

    location /media{
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/media;
    }

    location /{
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/project/project.sock;
    }

    location /wordpress {
        alias /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/wordpress/.+\.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the code bellow:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name sample.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem;


    location =/fabicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}

    location /static{
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
    }

    location /media{
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/media;
    }

    location /{
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/project/project.sock;
    }

    location /wordpress {
        alias /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        location ~ /wordpress/.*\.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
    }
```